# Select punctuation character with jQuery

Tags: jquery, clock

I've got this clock w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

Basically, I would like to make the ":" flicker. (visible/hidden)
I think I must select the ":" with jQuery and then change the visibility css property but I don't know how because they are generated by jQuery already...

As far as I've read, Regex might be a solution to make the selection but I don't know how to use it.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You can split the different parts of the clock into spans.
And put the ":" into a class.

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="txt"> <span id="hours"></span><span class="blink">:</span><span id="minutes"></span><span class="blink">:</span><span id="seconds"></span>
    </div>
```

You will also need to add the numbers of the clock into seperate spans, so that the ":" won't get inserted and removed every second.

In the end you initialise an interval where you apply the blinking effekt to the "blink" class.

**JQuery:**

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    $("#hours").html(h);
    $("#minutes").html(m);
    $("#seconds").html(s);
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        startTime()
    }, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    startTime();
    $('.blink').each(function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        setInterval(function () {
            if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
                elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
            } else {
                elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

**Here is a working DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UsnFR/